Unique numerical solution to Lippmann-Schwinger (Fredholm) equation
I am working in non-relativistic scattering theory and solving the Lippmann-Schwinger equations for the $T$ matrix in momentum space:
$$T_{fi}(k_f,k_i) = V_{fi}(k_f,k_i) + \sum_n\int_0^\infty \frac{V_{fn}(k_f,k)T_{ni}(k,k_i)}{E-\epsilon_n-k^2/2+i\epsilon}\,dk. $$
By discretising the $k$ domain we end up with a system of linear equations which we solve. We care only about the physical $T$-matrix elements $T_{fi}(k_f,k_i)$ (where the outgoing and incident momenta $k_f$ and $k_i$ are linked by the excitation energy of each transition between target states $i\rightarrow f$). As it turns out, these elements are all unique, but the "off-shell" matrix elements $T_{fi}(k,k_i)$ with $k\neq k_f$ are not unique. What this amounts to is that different choices of the $k$ discretisation will give different solutions, which will all converge at the point $k=k_f$. In principle not a problem except that it leads to a highly ill-conditioned linear system which leads to numerical instability in the on-shell values.
We have a technique for modifying the $V$-matrix elements algebraically in such a way that a unique solution is enforced, however it is only applicable to certain problems and is by no means a general solution to the problem. It does however illustrate that there are ways that you can modify a system of this form in a way that places an additional constraint on the off-shell solution without modifying the on-shell values.
I would like to find a way to do the same thing from a purely numerical point of view.
After some manipulation of the equation above, we end up solving a Fredholm equation of the form
$$ f(x) = g(x,x_i) + \mathcal P \int_0^\infty \frac{g(x,x')}{x_0^2-x'^2}f(x') \, dx', $$
where $x_i$ is a fixed value determined by the collision energy, $\mathcal P$ indicates the principle-value integral, so that the discretised $x$ grid on which we obtain the solution $f(x')$ does not actually contain the one value $f(x_0)$ we need. This value is obtained by substituting the solution $f(x')$ back into the Fredholm equation and evaluating with $x=x_0$ in the function $g(x,x_i)$.
What kind transformations can I apply to the kernel $K(x,x')$ and the function $g(x)$ such that the solution $f(x)$ is unaffected only at the specific point $x_0$?
We find that whenever we encounter numerical instability in the on-shell solution it tends to correspond to the off-shell values becoming very large and then coming down with a very large derivative towards the on-shell point. If there is a way to somehow constrain the derivative at the on-shell point that would be very attractive.
I've tried asking similar questions in the mathematics stack exchange without any luck, so thought I'd see if anyone here has any insight since it's usually physicists solving Fredholm equations.

What is exactly the form of the linear equation that you get?  I would say it has the form $(1-K) f =g$. So the solution is $f =(1-K)^{-1}g + f_0$, where $f_0$ is any solution of the homogeneous equation. This is well defined when $1-K$ is invertible, in other words the problems are eigenvalues one (or close to one) of $K$. A general approach to a solution would be to consider the pseudo-inverse. I suspect this is essentially similar to what you're doing (adding a perturbation and then removing it). But it may be more systematic.

If you have no luck getting an answer here you can try the computational science stack exchange: https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Thanks @MartinC., I will try that next.

@lcv, yes that is the form of the equations. In particular, the kernel of the Fredholm equation we solve is singular at the particular point $x_0$ that we actually care about, and its really the principle-value integral we are evaluating so the singular point does not end up in the linear system we solve. I've edited the equation in my post to illustrate that.

The part where you say that you want to know if there is a way to constrain the derivative at the on-shell point, seems to suggest that maybe you should analytically manipulate the principle value integral in such a way as to eliminate the singularity, thereby ensuring that numerical uncertainties cannot blow up. In any case, I really think that your problem is no longer something you can generalise so well, and instead you should try to work things out for your specific case.

Another approach would be an iterative solution. Have you tried that? It may be more stable. Usually the convergence is exponential (provided there is some gap somewhere I guess)
